# static method with same name & different param doesn't work

Tags: typescript

```
/********************* Parent.ts *********************/
class Parent {
    static connect(state?: string) {
        if (state) {
            // compile error
            logBar(state); // need to call logBar() in class Son.
                           // I can't call Son.logBar() since it is in Son.ts
        } else {
            // compile error
            logBar(); // need to call logBar in this class.
        }
    }

    static logBar() {
        console.log("2");
    }
}

/********************* Son.ts *********************/
// compile error :
// Class static side 'typeof Son' incorrectly extends base class
// static side 'typeof Parent'. Types of property 'logBar' are incompatible.
// Type '(state: string) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
class Son extends Parent {
    static logBar(state: string) {
        console.log("1");
    }

}

/********************* test.ts *********************/

Parent.connect();
Parent.connect("hi");
```

When `Parent.connect();` is called, it should print out "2".

When `Parent.connect("hi");` is called, it should print out "1".

Sadly abstract static isn't possible. And they are put in different file so I can't call like Parent.logBar() or Son.logBar(state).
How do I do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't import Son into Parent.ts?

Comment: i can but only if my intend doesn't work in typescript

Comment: You can't access a method in the Son subclass from Parent. If you instead put the connect method in Son instead, it will have access to both overloaded method definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you're confused about how classes and statics work.  Namely:

- You can't have a super class that calls methods *defined* on a sub class.  Essentially, `Parent` can't depend on `Son` existing.
- You can't overload a super class's methods.  So even if `Parent` could depend on `Son`, it can't change `logBar`s definition.
- A sub class being defined isn't going to affect what's done through references to the super class.  Nothing you put in `Son` is going to affect what `Parent.logBar(...)` does.

If you have to use classes and statics, you're only real option is to combine everything into `Parent`.  It'd look something like:

```js
class Parent {
  static connect(state?: string): void {
    if (state) {
          Parent.logWithState(state);
      } else {
          // compile error
          Parent.logNoState();
      }
  }

  static logWithState(state: string): void {
    console.log("1");
  }
  static logNoState(): void 
  {
    console.log("2");
  }
}
```

If you want to use inheritance, and can give up statics, you could do something like:

```js
class Parent {
  connect(state?: string): void {
    if (state) {
          this.logWithState(state);
      } else {
          // compile error
          this.logNoState();
      }
  }

  logWithState(state: string): void { }
  logNoState(): void { }
}

class Son extends Parent{
  logWithState(state: string) {
    console.log("1");
  }
  logNoState() {
    console.log("2");
  }
}

let ref: Parent = new Son();
ref.connect();
ref.connect("hi");
```

The second approach would let you sub out different sub-classes of `Parent`, if you needed to vary the behavior of your different methods at runtime.